# Laravel Eloquent extract only categories from places

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to create an array only with the categories that exist in a specific town (categories such as clubs, bars, etc.)

I have written this code in the controller which gets the town with the the data needed for the view:

```
    $town = Town::where('identifier', $town)->with(['places' => function($q) {
        $q->with('location')->with('categories')->with('minimum');
    }])->withCount('places')->first();
```

How can i create an array ONLY with the categories that exist in this query?

**Edit

The town has many places, the places belong to many categories.

Town Model:

```
   public function places()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::class);
    }
```

Place Model :

```
public function town() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Town::class);
}

public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(PlaceCategory::class, 'place_place_category');
}
```

Place Category Model:

```
public function places() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Place::class, 'place_place_category');
}
```

Comment: Can you post your models along with table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Ameer answer and made it work like this

```
    $categories = PlaceCategory::whereHas('places', function($q) use ($town) {
        $q->where('town_id', $town->id);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

the desired result for that can be done with **whereHas**, as the following:

```
$categories = Category::whereHas("town")->get();
```

Im assuming here you have defined the belongsTo relationship on the category model where the each category belongs to town (the reverse of each town has many categories).

Comment: Edited the question, then town has many places, the places belong to many categories.